# Defining a taxRate and applying it to a user's inputted annual income

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

taxRate does not exist in the current context. How can I apply it to the if/else if statements?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">
       Annual Income: <asp:TextBox ID="income" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br /><br />
       Number of dependents: <asp:TextBox ID="dependents" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="calculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate Tax" OnClick="calculate_Click" />
    <br /><br />        
       Total Tax: <asp:TextBox ID="total" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

taxRate is where my problem is, I have it as a double and its initial value is 1. Is that going to be a problem? I am getting a warning saying that its value is never used.

```
namespace WebApplication1 
{
public partial class Form1 : System.Web.UI.Page  {

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
    {

    }

protected void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int num1 = Int32.Parse(income.Text);
    int num2 = Int32.Parse(dependents.Text);
    int TaxableIncome = num1 - (num2 * 1000);
    double taxRate = 1;
    if (TaxableIncome <= 15000) taxRate = 0.10;
    else if (TaxableIncome <= 71000 && TaxableIncome > 15000) taxRate = 0.15;
    else if (TaxableIncome <= 192000 && TaxableIncome > 71000) taxRate = 0.25;
    else if (TaxableIncome <= 378000 && TaxableIncome > 192000) taxRate = 0.28;
    else if (TaxableIncome <= 450000 && TaxableIncome > 378000) taxRate = 0.33;
    else if (TaxableIncome > 450000) taxRate = 0.396;
    total.Text = TaxableIncome.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Declare taxRate before the if statements.

Comment: @deathismyfriend would it be an int and equal to zero? EDITED

Comment: You can set it to 1 when declaring it that way it will always have a value

Comment: @deathismyfriend with double taxRate = 1; I get a warning saying that taxRate is assigned but its value is never used.

Comment: As I said on my post below you need to use taxRate. Currently you are only declaring and setting it not using it for any other purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare taxRate in the method to be able to use it.

```
protected void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal taxRate = 1;
    // the if statements here 
    // use taxRate for whatever else here. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't use it.  You assign the rate but after the if block never do a calculation with it or anything else.  In your last line do this:

```
total.Text = (taxRate * TaxableIncome).ToString();
```

I would set taxRate to zero as one will result in a 100% tax if you goofed something.

A bit off topic, if this is for USA federal tax that calculation is too simple as income tax is graduated.